# How to create infowindow for each marker in google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create three markers with different values. Within a for loop I have the following:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: point, clickable: true});

marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: '<b>Speed:</b> ' + values.inst + ' knots'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  marker.info.open(map, marker);
});
```

The issue I am having is when I click on any of the 3 markers, only an infowindow for the very last marker created pops up. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move this code out of the `for` loop and into a separate function that you call from the `for` loop. If you post more of your code, including the loop and the array the loop iterates over, I could give more specific advice.

But as an example:

```
var places = [
    { lat:1, lng:1, name:'one one' }
    { lat:-1, lng:-1, name:'minus one one' }
];

for( var i = 0, n = places.length;  i < n;  i++ ) {
    addPlace( places[i] );
}

function addPlace( place ) {
    // here you have place.lat, place.lng, and place.name to work with
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you'll find useful the below example:

```
var cityList = [
            ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
            ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
        ]

function addMarkers()
{
    var marker, 
    i,
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++) 
    {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
            map: map,
            title: cityList[i][0]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(cityList[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```